# Can't install Beautifulsoup ("bs4 does not exist")

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm struggling to get BeautifulSoup installed on Windows. So far, I have:

1. downloaded BeautifulSoup to "My Downloads".
2. unzipped/ extracted it in the downloads folder.
3. At the command prompt, I ran:

   ```
   C:<path to python33> "C:path to beautiful soup\setup.py" install
   ```

The process generated the messages:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
**error: package directory 'bs4' does not exist.**
```

Yet, in the path to BeautifulSoup in quotes above, there is indeed the folder `bs4`. What am I missing?

Comment: What error occurs in your installation process? Post the traps you meet will help others help you.

Comment: Thanks.. current steps/ errors added.

Comment: What is your working directory? It should be the directory containing setup.py.

Comment: Thanks. Cd did it. I've never done anything at the command prompt before. I see the question has drawn the ire of (4), feel free to close it. I am in business.

Comment: I don't understand why they were wishing to close it. It's certainly not off-topic as they are claiming.

Comment: I found the same question (differing exact circumstances) that were upvoted. Who knows. Thanks again.

Answer (score 10):

You need to be in the directory containing `setup.py` to run it. Make sure your working directory is correct.

Comment: The above was my issue, so thanks @Chris Morgan. :-) (Windows machine, here).

Comment: Exactly what I did wrong, thank you. This should be flag as the correct answer

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem. In my case, I was able to get pip to work, but first I had to look up the right name for the package:

wrong: pip install bs4

#### fail

wrong: pip install beautifulsoup

#### fail

right: pip install beautifulsoup4

#### Successfully installed beautifulsoup4

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem when tryingo to export my wordpress blog to jekyll with [this tutorial](https://github.com/thomasf/exitwp).

My first step was to install pip with success & next try to install BeautifulSoup with it:

```
pip install bs4 # failed
pip install BeautifulSoup # that was succes
```

But... 2nd line install BeatifulSoup3, not most recent version 4...

So I've uninstalled bs3:

```
pip uninstall BeautifoulSoup # with success
```

Downloaded most recent bs4 from [this site](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/) & installed it manually within command/mingw:

```
cd %bs4-download-dir%
python setup.py install
```

And now everything is OK :)

Answer (score 2):

**For clean install without pip nor easy_install :**

**Your paths**
*(change it by your paths)*

1. Your python path :  c:\Python27\python.exe
2. Your beautyfulsoup path : c:\BeautifulSoup

**Instruction to follow for clean installation :**

3. cd c:\BeautifulSoup
4. "c:\Python27\python.exe" setup.py install

Have fun and share !

“Any fool can know. The point is to understand.”

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the batch file you used to run "python" "\beautifulsoup4-4.3.1\setup.py" install is in the same directory as "\beautifulsoup4-4.3.1\setup.py"